# Not able to send login info request via AJAX call

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am trying to grab the user_ID and password typed by user and sending it to Server. Here's my Javascript code;

```
    <script>

    function Display(){
        var ID = document.getElementById("user_id").value;
        document.getElementById("user_id_D").innerHTML =  ID;

        var pass = document.getElementById("password_id").value;


       var login = "login:" + ID + "-" + pass;
       document.getElementById("password_id_D").innerHTML =  login;

        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.onreadystatechange = function(){
          if(this.readyState === 4){
            if (this.status === 200) {
              if (this.responseText !== null) {
          }
             }
        }
        };  
        request.open("GET",login, true);
        request.send(null);

       }
    </script>
```

HTML (Bootstrap):

```
      <form class="form col-md-12 center-block">
        <input type="text" id="user_id" placeholder="User ID">
        <input type="password" id="password_id" placeholder="Password">
        <button onclick="Display()">Sign In</button>
      </form>
```

When I write my ID and password and press SignIn button, The browser gives me an error "NS_ERROR_UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL: " at line "request.open("GET",login, true);" ... What can be the possible reason for that ?

Comment: what is the url for the request... and what should be the data?

Comment: Note: The login request should not be a get request, should be a post

Comment: I've tried with POST as well but same error. My server code is running on Python. if I write "request.open("GET","hello", true);" , I receive the request "Hello" in python server, but when I try to sent login (login="login:" + ID + "-" + pass, it gives me that error.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this code

```
 request.open("GET",login, true);
```

The second param is **a valid URI** . Also you can attach login information via url or data in http POST method.

Comment: But thats the same line as i wrote. Whats new in it ?

Comment: i mean that 2nd param is a valid url with protocol (http or https) like : `http://example`. So your code should be :   `request.open("GET","http://example.com/login-path", true);`

Answer (score 0):

I made it work, Actually I was missing the "/" before making login request. Now i am sending

```
request.open("GET",login, true);
```

where my 'login' request is;

```
var login = "/login:" + ID + "-" + pass;
```